# Почему в Яндекс-вебмастере такие загадочные страницы с кодом 404?

Tags: joomla, seo

Есть сайт Joomla 3 + Virtuemart 3.0.6 (http://alcopribor.ru).

В Яндекс-вебмастере в разделе "Индексирование сайта - Исключенные (404) страницы" присутствует толпа ссылок навроде:

```
catalog/skidki-i-aktsii-smotret-vse/manufacturer/by,`p`.ratings/results,25-24

catalog/skidki-i-aktsii-smotret-vse/manufacturer/by,`p`.ratings/results,49-48

catalog/skidki-i-aktsii-smotret-vse/by,`p`.ratings/results,265-264

catalog/skidki-i-aktsii-smotret-vse/manufacturer/by,`p`.ratings/results,241-240
```

Откуда могут браться адреса страниц, напоминающие в хвосте некий SQL-запрос? Как такие страницы попали в поле зрения Яндекса? (Вирусов на сайте не наблюдаю, проверял; robots.txt вполне джумловский).

Comment: Добавьте содержимое `robots.txt`, пожалуйста

Comment: Вот ссылка на него (ибо в комменты содержимое не влазит увы):
http://alcopribor.ru/robots.txt

Спасибо!

Comment: используется родное ЧПУ или стоит SEO-компонент какой-то?

Comment: Родное SEF + ЧПУ Артио.

Answer (score 1):

Разобрались с проблемой несколько брутально: просто запретили индексировать такие страницы в robots.txt. Дело оказалось в том, что в давние времена на ядре сайта стояла Joomla 1.5, в которой были такого вида ссылки для некоего расширенного поиска. Сейчас J3 у которой такого нет, а ссылки всё равно шли в поисковики)